# product id in android with respect to in app billing

Tags: android, product, in-app-billing

I have a requirement that, there are a set of media files in my app, now if any one wants to see them, he should buy those files.

In iPhone, we have something called product id for this, to uniquely identify the files in the app, now I want to know do we have anything like that in android?

And also could any one show me code snippet of doing in app purchase 
(Note : Except  the one in the android developer site, I went through that)

Thanks in Advance,

Tejaswi Marakini

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple product ids just like iOS IAP. For IAB, I am afraid the Dungeon example is the place to start with and work over.